# Leaflet offline tiles problem

Tags: leaflet, windows, tile-map-service

I hate to ask this kind of questions, but i ve been stuck for 2 days now:

I rendered some tiles with mapnik which i want to serve in my offline application which will run from a portable disk, but via browser still. I switched openlayers to leaflet for this particular case because of its nice widgets and seemingly easier setup.

However, i initialize my map and tile layer like this:

```
var map = L.map('map_canvas');
map.setView([50, 10.0], 6);      

var layer = L.tileLayer('./data/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.png', { maxZoom: 16 , tms: true});    
map.addLayer(layer);
```

But what i get is a blank map. If i inspect whats going on with Firebug it seems that tiles are not even being requested (no other errors either). The map is set up right because i can see leaflet map widgets, i suspect its got something to do with the url of the layer. I copied that directly from my other OpenLayers app which works without a problem. Any ideas, or has anyone else stumbled across this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, leave out the $ symbols.

Comment: Did so, but still no luck, good point though!

Comment: Okay, one more update, i added the layer from the example which gets its data from cloudmade server. It works, so im guessing it really is something about the path

Comment: Aha, found the issue, i had to set tms: false, because i reversed the axis when i generated the tiles. Blah :) I hate it when i post a question then hours later i find the solution

Comment: Good question - helpful for me, especially `tms: true` and @Calvin's answer below with regards to local, Windows files.

Comment: I'm using file:///C:/path/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png like url in tileLayer but it doesn't work and no error is shown. Any idea? Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To give an answer to this: You can set relative paths, this is no problem. But the URL has to look like this (without the dollar signs).

```
var map = L.map('map_canvas');
map.setView([50, 10.0], 6);      

var layer = L.tileLayer('data/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 16 });    
map.addLayer(layer);
```

where `data` is a subdirectory of the current directory, where the html file with this javascript code is executed.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have relative urls off line, you need to have a file protocol (file://) absolute url, you can right click on an image and open it in a browser to get the url path.

```
var map = L.map('map_canvas');
map.setView([50, 10.0], 6);      

var layer = L.tileLayer('file:///c://path/to/your/data/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { maxZoom: 16 , tms: true});    
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Comment: In this case it would only be usable from the local system which contains the tiles.

Comment: Not true at all, relative urls work without a problem :)

Comment: @Calvin - I think it needs to be like: `file:///L:/Imagery/2011/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` if this was an external hard drive assigned 'L' in Windows. You're showing one less '/' before the drive letter and one too-many '/' in your example.